# How to auto Generate Menus If a module is installed in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, menu, laravel-8

Here's my goal.

I'm Creating a laravel application and I split different functions in modules using NWIDART module.

On my side menu I used pre defined code to check if module exists and if module enabled, then show the menu using the module as a name. But for future purpose when I have a new module and don't wish to go back to edit my core code and include the new module name I want the module to be auto added when I installed the module.

Now just like WordPress plugins, not all plugins have menu except pre defined in the plugin core file.  I should also be able to pre define in my Module Codes if a menu is to be added.

So when the new module is uploaded, if menu is to be added, then add a new menu else don't add menu.

Please any ideas how to set this type of feature up?